# re a cHow can I connect my Evolution client to my Outlook.com account?

Tags: email, thunderbird, evolution

I am having trouble connecting to the Outlook.com free account using my Evolution client.

## IMAP

```
imap-mail.outlook.com
port 993
TLS on a dedicated port
```

## SMTP

```
smtp-mail.outlook.com
587
STARTTLS after connecting
```

Looks like the information is correct. But I am still unable to connect.

## ERROR

**Could not connect to imap-mail.outlook.com: Network is unreachable**

Could you please help?

Is there a configuration I am missing. My client works fine with my work Email.

Answer (score 0):

The host names and ports are correct for the Outlook servers. Note however that "Network is unreachable" has absolutely nothing to do with the configuration of the e-mail client. This is a network configuration issue. It usually indicates that your routing table is misconfigured. Since these are Internet servers, it is very likely that the default route is not properly set up. Also, you may have misconfigured your proxy settings (either you are behind a proxy without having it configured or the other way around).

Comment: Thank you! I am behind an organization proxy. please note that the same client is able to connect to another Email account. Is there anything I am missing.

Comment: @ferengi The proxy could mess up everything related to the ports. Maybe the other account you have configured in Evolution uses other Ports (143 for reception and 25 for sending).

Comment: Actually, that is true. It does use different proxies. But I thought proxies are configured account wise---

Comment: I do not see any proxy configuration possibility in Evolution. It is left up to the network configuration.